# JavaFX coordinate system defaults to YUp

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, scenebuilder

In my JavaFX Application, I use [SceneBuilder by Gluon](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjEwOeGt_HNAhUI_R4KHVaYCj4QFgg2MAM&url=http%3A%2F%2Fgluonhq.com%2Flabs%2Fscene-builder%2F&usg=AFQjCNEmlYrlrDR_b4s24BXPgOSzW5prIA&sig2=faVExx6J4QyNcrCCJIwR-w). The preview for the scene has a coordinate system of Y Down (Y increases downwards). However, when I import the fxml file into Java, the coordinates are all flipped. Here are the relevant screenshots.

Here is the Java export:
[image: Java application]
And here is the SceneBuilder preview:
[image: SceneBuilder preview]

From what I have gathered from extensive Googling, the JavaFX coordinate system should be Y-Down, not Y-Up. Is there something wrong with my version of JavaFX? I'm on Mac OS X 10.12 (El Capitan), using JDK 1.8.0_66.

Comment: What JDK version and what OS are you using? Also, since you have the reputation, can you include the images in your question instead of linking them?

Comment: @James_D I've added OS and JDK info, along with images.

Comment: Could you add the fxml code to the question?

Comment: @fabian Unfortunately, I will not have access to my workspace until tomorrow.

Comment: I use the [Oracle Scene Builder 2.0](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafxscenebuilder-1x-archive-2199384.html) which is also available for OSX with JDK 1.8.0.91 which works like expected

Answer (score 1):

The default orientation in JavaFX is definitely y-down and there is no difference between SceneBuilder and any other JavaFX application. Of course you can apply a transform which changes this orientation but the default is as expected. Without seeing your fxml it is impossible to tell what is going on here. My guess would be that there is a difference in the containers into which your fxml is loaded. The visual difference may then be caused by different layout behaviours of these containers.

Comment: This is certainly possible. However, before I used SceneBuilder, I had a completely organic stage setup, and the coordinate system of that setup was still y-up. As it stands, I will include the fxml data.