# JavaFX coordinates inverted on the Y-axis with respect to Swing

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, scenebuilder

[Previously](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38362498/230513), I asked a question comparing the SceneBuilder coordinates with JavaFX's output. I have come to realize that the problem did not lie within SceneBuilder and the exported FXML code; but it is, in fact, a problem with my machine's version of JavaFX. However, I'm still unclear as to why this happens.

In my FXML code, I have the following hierarchy:

```
<AnchorPane id="rootPane" pickOnBounds="false" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.65" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <StackPane id="game">
      <AnchorPane id="hud" style="-fx-background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">
         <Text id="ammo" fontSmoothingType="LCD" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="699.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="0" wrappingWidth="111.21875">
            <font>
               <Font name="Brother Deluxe 1350 Font" size="48.0" />
            </font>
            <effect>
               <DropShadow color="#0000007a" height="16.0" offsetY="1.0" radius="5.5" width="8.0" />
            </effect>
         </Text>
      </AnchorPane>
   </StackPane>
</AnchorPane>
```

This produces the following output from IntelliJ:
[image: Java export with inverted Y coordinates]

As you can see, the Y coordinates are flipped, with 0,0 being in the bottom left of the screen. But in SceneBuilder, the output is what I would normally expect:
[image: SceneBuilder preview with proper Y coordinates]

If necessary, the full code can be found [here](https://github.com/officialexosoft/Zerfall-Java/tree/JavaFX/src/exosoft/zerfall).

My question is, why is my JavaFX application producing an interface with 0,0 being at the bottom left instead of the top left, as my research indicates it should be? And if possible, how can I fix this problem?

My operating system is OS X 10.12, El Capitan. My JDK version is 1.8.0_66.

Comment: Why do you not use the root of the FXML (`rootPane`) as your root element, but instead wrap `game` in a new `Group`? This may be problematic (not sure, though).

Comment: @sillyfly It's because I need a `Group` to instantiate the `Scene`.

Comment: You can instantiate the `Scene` with any `Parent`, not just a `Group`. If you must use a `Group`, why not put it in the FXML?

Comment: @sillyfly One second, I'll see what happens when I remove the `Group` from the equation.

Comment: @sillyfly Nothing changes, unfortunately

Comment: What makes you think it's _flipped_ and not _translated_? What happens with `text="7"`?

Comment: @trashgod It's really not that difficult to understand... In the SceneBuilder render, the text is 699 pixels from the top of the screen, as it should be. In the JavaFX export, the text is 699 pixels from the *top of the screen*. If you look at the images closely, the 0 in the IntelliJ render is thinner on the bottom, while the 0 in the SceneBuilder render is thinner on the *top*. So it is flipped. **My question is** ***why***.

Comment: There is a bug filed with `SceneAntialiasing.BALANCED` on [Mac](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8139197?jql=text%20~%20%22SceneAntialiasing.BALANCED%22) that flipped the scene. Use a newer JDK version, as it should be fixed, or remove antialiasing.

Comment: @JoséPereda I'll check to see if that works. Cheers!

Comment: @JoséPereda It worked. Would you mind posting an answer so I can mark it as correct?

Comment: Sure, did you update the JDK?

Comment: @JoséPereda Just removed the antialiasing for the moment, but I will be updating my jdk at the earliest convenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a [bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8136495) with `SceneAntialiasing.BALANCED` on Mac that flipped the scene. It was filed based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32525086/javafx-rendering-issue-on-osx-after-java-upgrade) and it is already fixed for Java 9 and back ported to recent versions of JDK 8.

The solution is just updating to the [latest](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloa%E2%80%A6) JDK version if possible.

If not, removing the antialiasing parameter or using `SceneAntialiasing.DISABLED` works as well.